# Get Process builder action details in APEX

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, process-builder

I have an object Inv with status field. There is a visualforce page for this Inv object field operations. That page has a button 'Mark as complete', On clicking this button, Apex code changes Inv.Status__c field to 'Complete'. There is a process builder on this Inv object which checks for this 'Complete' status and Create a record in PT object.

This was already existing project. I am given a requirement to show another visualforce page "VF_page1" (like popup), one of the page parameters of this VF_page1 has to be the Id of the PT record created using the process builder.

Is there a way to get this PT.Id ? Can I do below things using APEX code?

1. In Apex code, Prevent the process being invoked for the next
   update
2. Update the Status to Complete
3. Pull a few default values
   which are mentioned in process builder action and Create PT object
   record in code after setting the default values. This way I will get
   the newly created PT record Id. I could pass this to the VF_page1.

Please suggest

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but what is PT?

Comment: PT is actually another object.

Comment: Okay, thought you were using an abbreviation - thanks

Comment: They are abbreviations actually. I am not allowed to share the real object, page name details as per my company policy.

Comment: Is there any relation between Inv to PT if Yes Then You can SOQL on that with his relations and created date.Hope it will help you. Thanks Regards, Akshay

Comment: I completely understand :)

Answer (score 0):

Apex is used when you see no ability to solve the issue/requirement with standard out of the box functionalities, guaranteeing maintainability and flexibility of the org.

I see at this point a solution with apex - that you can implement.  In general, you would need an extra technical field on the INV object to store the ID. (**Here I took the assumption they are both not linked by lookup/master-detail, so completely seperate objects**)

- Create an update trigger that does the PT creation.
- After the object is created, use the ID to update the technical field.  Make sure you make this trigger able to run in batch because of governor limits.